# How to read a file but only the context after the = in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, config

Hello i am creating a web browser and i want to have a config file. My config file goes like this

```
# (a commend to help with editing the config file) 
default-webpage = google.com
dark-mode = true
```

and many more things and i want to put the context before and after the = on a dictionary when i can access and take the values from it to put them in the code and my code so far is this

```
config = open("config.cfg", "r")
context = config.readlines()
```

and what i am trying to do is open the config file and then read the lines in a way that i can choose which line to have by using

```
print (context[1])
```

To read the second line
can someone help????

Comment: Maybe the built-in module [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) will help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code a solution manually, you can try the following to split each line into a key-value pair and store it in a config dictionary:

```
config = open("config.cfg", "r")
context = config.readlines()
config_dict = {}
for line in context:
    split_line = line.split('=')
    key, value = split_line[0].strip(), split_line[1].strip()
    config_dict[key] = value
```

Then you can get the value for `default-webpage` by `config_dict['default-webpage']`.

Comment: thanks but when i runed it it sayed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\John\Documents\GitHub\SimplePythonBrowser\Simple_browser.py", line 19, in <module>
    key, value = split_line[1].strip(), split_line[2].strip()
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You're using the incorrect index (1 and 2). List indexing starts from zero, so you need to use (0 and 1) instead. `key, value = split_line[0].strip(), split_line[1].strip()`